# How does the YubiKey Validation Server work from an encryption perspective?

Tags: encryption, cryptography, multi-factor, yubikey

Many YubiKey servers rely on the free cloud hosted authentication that comes with the product, but I'm interested in keeping all cryptographic material in my control.  For that reason I am looking at the Validation Server.

The official [YubiKey Validation Server source code is written in a language](http://code.google.com/p/yubikey-val-server-php/) I'm not entirely familliar with, and would rather read a specification.  And from what I can tell it isn't based on HOTP RFC 4226; TOTP RFC, like Google Authenticator.

Can anyone explain how this server (and corresponding device keys) work from an encryption perspective?

Answer (score 7):

Both the validation server and YubiKey OTP use a uniquely-structured AES-encrypted key for validation. The security information about the Yubico Validation server and YubiKey OTP is available [here](https://%20www.yubico.com/wpcontent/uploads/2012/10/Security-Evaluation-v2.0.1.pdf).

You can also discuss the validation server with other users on the [Yubico forums](https://forum.yubico.com).

Comment: Hello David, welcome to security.SE! It is great that you directly indicate your affiliation, but in contrast to a forum we prefer putting this in the "About me" section of the user section instead - that way it will always be up to date (and when you have gained 1000 rep, the text will be shown when hovering over your user icon: http://security.stackexchange.com/privileges/established-user)

Comment: The first link points to a nonexistent page. Can you update the URL?